# Enabling Geolocation for localhost in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, geolocation

I am pretty new to Javascript/html5. I am basically working off code provided in Rbon Nixon's book (4th Edition, Learning PHP, MySQL and Javascript...). Example 22-2 of which is about "displaying the map at a user's location".
I am getting caught in the if part of the following code snippet:

```
    <script>
        if (typeof navigator.Geolocation=='undefined')
            alert("Geolocation not supported.")
    </script>
```

Superficially, it seems quite obvious that I should enable geolocation int eh browser for localhost. I am using chrome (Version 60.0.3112.113). But when I go to Settings >> Advanced >> Content Settings >> Location
the ask before accessing option is enabled. and then there are the Block and Allow sections. But it does not give me an option to add localhost. How do I enable it so that I can use geolocation in my code and test it on my machine?

Comment: It's `navigator.geolocation`, with lowercase `g`. Typo?

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. My bad.